# How to add a UIImage to a UIScrollView without breaking the scrolling function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView filling my entire view, which was placed using Interface Bilder. I also placed numerous buttons in my scrollable area, all of which works great.

However, I would like to insert a large UIImage to fill my view as well. When I add the UIImage, the view is no longer scrollable. At first I thought the UIImage might be 'blocking' the UIScrollView, so I arranged it to be sent to back, but it didn't help. Does anyone know how to get my UIImage and UIScrollView to play nice?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think you need some more details about what your view hierarchy is like. Is the UIImageView a child of or sister of the UIScrollView? What are the sizes and positions of all the views?

Comment: add your code for reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Image views by default do not have this option set to yes, and they capture all touch events - keeping the scroll view from ever seeing it.

Comment: I added that line to my viewWillAppear method:     _backImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES; but I still can't scroll.

Comment: Try it in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the interface builder there might be two reasons for not scrolled:

1. The `UIScrollView` size is bigger than the `UIImage` Size, in this case It will not be scrolled.
2. `UIImage` is not added to the `UIScrollView` content size.

Try this:

```
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(4500, 320)];
[myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```